# perl sed escaping quantifiers from a regex

Tags: regex, perl

Having trouble removing quantifiers and meta characters from a regex with sed.
To complicate matters the code is intended to be used within a eval.

```
$word_check = "about\s*[\w\s]+";
$word_check =~ s/\\\[.+\\\]//g;
$$word_count[$#$word_count + 1] += () = $word_check =~ /(\w+)\s*/g;
```

Word_check is a copy of a regex. Want to reduce the regex to only the words it is to
match. Using a regex to do so. Then count the words and save the result in a array.
The reason behind the choice is the regex is apart of several and when working with 
a match ($&) the words are removed. From a eval. The code below is intended as a string.

```
for ( my \$i = 0; \$i < \$\$ref_word_count[\$R]; \$i++ ) {
    \$temp_str =~ s/^\\w+\\s*//;
}
```

OK  Found the answer. Just needed to break up the sed statement some and see the square brackets as a character alone.

```
$word_check =~ s/i$//;
$word_check =~ s/[\.\+]//g;
$word_check =~ s/\\[sdwSWD]//g;
$word_check =~ s/[[]//g;
$word_check =~ s/[]]//g;
$word_check =~ s/[*]//g;
$word_check =~ s/[?]//g;
```

Comment: Your question is not quite clear. What exactly you want to do? Can you post a working example, with an input and expected output?

Answer (score 1):

Probably this helps

> \Q          quote (disable) pattern metacharacters till \E
>
> \E          end either case modification or quoted section, think vi

See [perldoc perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Escape-sequences)

Comment: This worked great for me when I had an empty string that wasn't working. Thanks :)